# Eclipse Plugin development with Kotlin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, kotlin

I'd like to develop an Eclipse Plugin with Kotlin, but I can't find info about how to configure the project. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Why do you want to develop such a plugin if one plugin like this already exists?

Comment: @DinaBogdan Hi! I think you misunderstood. I want to develop plugins USING Kotlin